# About more than 15 stars moving in straight line through the sky

Tags: star-systems

I had seen more than 15 stars are moved in a straight line through the sky just like a train. And the distance between each star was not same, some of them were near and some of them were far. The intensity of the light of each star was also different. I had seen this phenomena on 21st November 2019 at Indian time 5:30 AM in my place. What could that have been?

Answer (score 2):

These will be SpaceX's second batch of 60 [Starlink](https://www.spacex.com/news/2019/11/11/starlink-mission) communications satellites. They were launched on 11 November 2019, and are still in roughly the same orbit, although they are slowly dispersing. Enjoy the show. There should be plenty more. SpaceX plans to launch several thousand of these satellites. Unfortunately, this is not good news for astronomers, since they may interfere with ground-based observations.

Answer (score 2):

As noted they are "Starlink" satellites
their presence is not without growing controversy in Astronomy.

https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2019/11/20/this-is-how-elon-musk-can-fix-the-damage-his-starlink-satellites-are-causing-to-astronomy/